# How to fix " Notice: Undefined index"

Tags: php

I login and choose not to remember it this error occurs

> Notice: Undefined index: isRemember in
>   web/controllers/cont.userForm.php on line 16

Code cont.userForm.php

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_GET['action'] == 'login' && $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){
        if($huy->isExist(APP_TABLES_PREFIX . 'user','id',array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>sha1($_POST['password'])))){
            $thisUser = $db->Query(APP_TABLES_PREFIX . 'user','role',array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>sha1($_POST['password'])));
            if($thisUser['0']['role'] == 0){
                $user->alert('danger',$l['email_not_confirmed']);
            }else{
                if ($_POST['isRemember'] == 0){
                    $user = $db->Query(APP_TABLES_PREFIX . 'user','*',array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>sha1($_POST['password'])));
                    $db->Update(APP_TABLES_PREFIX . 'user',array('email'=>$_POST['email']),array('last_login'=>$now));
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $user['0']['id'];
                    echo '...';

                }else{

                    $user = $db->Query(APP_TABLES_PREFIX . 'user','*',array('email'=>$_POST['email'],'password'=>sha1($_POST['password'])));
                    $db->Update(APP_TABLES_PREFIX . 'user',array('email'=>$_POST['email']),array('last_login'=>$now));
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $user['0']['id'];
                    setcookie("userId",  $user['0']['id'],  time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', NULL, 0 ); 
                    setcookie("hash",  md5($user['0']['id'].$user['0']['password']),  time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', NULL, 0 ); 
                    echo '...'; 
                }   
            }
        }else{
            $user-> alert('danger',$l['login_incorrect']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Checkboxes aren't sent in if not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter your if-statement to check wether the POST variable excists:

```
if (isset($_POST['isRemember'] && $_POST['isRemember'] == 1){
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

Since the checkbox won't be sent if it is unchecked and therefore an undefined index error occurs.